# Exclude inbox from IMAP syncing in thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail

In mbsync you can exclude any folder from syncing (including Inbox with a pattern like `!"INBOX"`). Is there any way to exclude Inbox in thunderbird? It would be useful when using gmail, because you can't "uncheck" Inbox from gmail's IMAP and it contains redundant messages that you may want to exclude like gmail's "categories" (labels that filter out spam messages like promotions, social media etc.).

I've checked "Properties" of Inbox folder, but none of the options seemed to allow for it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you right-click the account in the left pane of Thunderbird, you can select "Subscribe". There, you can unsubscribe from folders, including the "Inbox" folder. Then, that folder is not anymore displayed and not anymore synchronized.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. I'd never thought of that.